# Why cannot save subclass object in parent entity using entity framework 6.0

Tags: .net, entity-framework

My code of Model and DBcontext is below:

```
public class Person  
{  
   public string Name { get; set;}  
}

public class Student:Person  
{  
   public string Property { get; set;}  
}

public class TestContext: DbContext  
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    ....
   // I create two separated table Student, Person in DB.
}

public void run()  
{
    using(var db = new TestContext())  
    {
        // First
        var person = new Person { Name = "Brenda"};
        db.Person.Add(person);
        db.SaveChanges();// it works.

        // Second
        var student = new Student { Name = "Jason",Property = "Middle" };
        db.Students.Add(student);
        db.SaveChanges(); // it works.

        // Third
        var person1 = (Person)student;
        db.Persons.Add(person1);
        db.SaveChanges(); // it does not work! why?
    }  

}
```

Why I cannot save subclass object in parent entity? I have using the SQL Profiler to monitor the database, but can not track the 'Third one' trying to insert db. Is there anyone who can help me figure this issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Probably because `student` is already tracked by the context.

Comment: You might consider learning more about [Inheritance with EF Code First](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph)

Comment: @haim770, what do you mean? why I can not save it in person table.